# Request Azure Notification Hub device registration from Flutter app connected to Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: flutter, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to register an android emulator device through a Flutter app connected with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

The expected steps should be this:

Send a notification from FCM to the emulator (**works**) --->

Receive the notification on the android emulator (**works**) -->

Send device registration request to Azure Notification Hub (**fails!**) -->

Send a new notification from Flutter app to Azure Notification Hub.

I implemented the registration request in Flutter function as follows:

```
final url = 'https://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/name-of-the-hub';

  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Endpoint=sb://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=key-of-the-notification-hub',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: json.encode({
      'channelUri': 'fcmToken-from-emulator',
      'platform': 'gcm', // Use 'fcm' if targeting Firebase Cloud Messaging directly
    }),
  );

  print("Response status code: ${response.statusCode}");


  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    // Notification sent successfully
    print("Sending notification to Azure Notification Hub...");

    final url = 'https://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/name_of-the-hub';

    final response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Endpoint=sb://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=key-of-the-notification-hub',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: json.encode({
        'data': {
          'title': 'Hello',
          'body': 'This is a notification from Flutter App!',
        },
      }),
    );
    print("Response status code 2: ${response.statusCode}");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Notification sent successfully to Azure Notification Hub");
    } else {
      // Failed to send the notification
      print("Notification sending to Azure Notification Hub FAILED!");
    }
  } else {
    // Failed to request authorization
    print("Authorization request to Azure Notification Hub FAILED!");
  }
```

I also tried this alternative implementation:

```
final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  final String hubName = 'name-of-the-hub';
  final String hubConnectionString =
      'Endpoint=sb://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=key-of-the-hub';

  final String registrationEndpoint =
      'https://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$hubName';

  final String registrationId = '68937569214';

  final Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
    'platform': 'gcm',
    'deviceId': registrationId,
    'pushChannel': fcmToken,
  };

  final Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': hubConnectionString,
  };

  final String xmlPayload =
      '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">'
      '<content type="application/xml">'
      '<GcmRegistrationDescription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">'
      '<Tags>default</Tags>'
      '<RegistrationId>$registrationId</RegistrationId>'
      '<ChannelUri>$fcmToken</ChannelUri>'
      '</GcmRegistrationDescription>'
      '</content>'
      '</entry>';

  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(registrationEndpoint),
    headers: headers,
    body: xmlPayload,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    print('Registration successful');
  } else {
    print('Registration failed with status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');
  }
```

But nothing seems to be working correctly.
I always receive a 200 as registration request response code.
I also tried to look for a Dart package to make requests easier but I didn't find any package in in pub.dev website.
What am I doing wrong in the request ? Is there any missing field ?

Comment: could you please share your findings. Thanks